# issue with creating file containing $ from bash script

Tags: bash

I want produce udev rule file from bash script. For this I'm using cat command. Unfortunately produced file has missing "$" char. Here is example test.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh


rc=`cat <<stmt1 > ./test.txt

-p $tempnode
archive/$env{ID_FS_LABEL_ENC}

stmt1`
```

Result is following:

```
cat test.txt 

-p ''
archive/{ID_FS_LABEL_ENC}
```

Where issue is ?

Comment: try `archive/\$env{ID_FS_LABEL_ENC}` (mind the backslash)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want any variable interpolation, use:

```
#!/bin/sh

group="test_1"

cat <<'stmt1' > ./test.txt

-p $tempnode
archive/$env{ID_FS_LABEL_ENC}

stmt1
rc=$?
```

(Notice the `''` around `stmt1`.)